# mongo-csharp-driver 2.0 / nservicebus.mongodb 2.1 can no longer connect to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nservicebus

We recently updated our NserviceBus.MongoDb package from 2.0.3 to 2.1. This also updated the mongo-csharp-driver package from 1.10 to 2.0.1.  We now see the following exception when the service starts:

> 2015-07-08 11:29:16,589 [1] WARN  NServiceBus.MongoDB.Internals.MongoHelpers [(null)] <(null)> - Mongo could not be contacted using: server201.localco.test:27017.
>   If you are using a Replica Set, please ensure that all the Mongo instance(s) server201.localco.test:27017 are available.
>   To configure NServiceBus to use a different connection string add a connection string named "NServiceBus/Persistence" in your config file.
>   Reason: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no current primary.
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Ping()
>      at NServiceBus.MongoDB.Internals.MongoHelpers.VerifyConnectionToMongoServer(MongoClientAccessor mongoClientAccessor) in d:\Development\NServiceBus.MongoDB\src\NServiceBus.MongoDB\Internals\MongoHelpers.cs:line 50

The only relevant line in our nservicebus endpoint config is:

```
configuration.UsePersistence<MongoDBPersistence>();
```

and our connection string is:

```
<add name="NServiceBus.Persistence" connectionString="mongodb://server201.localco.test/?replicaSet=rs0" />
```

If I uninstall/rollback 2.1/2.0.1 to 2.0.3/1.10 (nservicebus.mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) the error goes away.

Update: I see that the database itself (with a TimoutData collection) is actually created in Mongo...

Comment: Check your assembly scanning

Comment: Can you be more specific?  This is the current config statements we have in total:

`public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {                       configuration.AssembliesToScan(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());                        
            configuration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
            configuration.UsePersistence<MongoDBPersistence>();                              
        }`

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment above (rolling back work ok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of the package from Github/Nuget has addressed this issue. [See bug report](https://github.com/sbmako/NServiceBus.MongoDB/issues/14)

Answer (score 2):

Change your connection string from

`<add name="NServiceBus.Persistence" connectionString="mongodb://server201.localco.test/?replicaSet=rs0" />`

to

`<add name="NServiceBus/Persistence/MongoDB" connectionString="mongodb://server201.localco.test/?replicaSet=rs0" />`

or leave it like above and set the name to

```
config
    .UsePersistence<MongoDbPersistence>()
    .SetConnectionStringName("NServiceBus.Persistence");
```

Comment: Changing the connection string doesn't seems to work:
`An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in NServiceBus.MongoDB.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot configure Mongo Persister. No connection string named NServiceBus.Persistence was found`

I tried both, changing the connection string and setting it explicitly in code. Same issue as original.

Comment: I've briefly looked at the code on the MongoDB persistence repo. It should work. Have you tried cloning the repo locally, checkout the exact version and debug the configuration code?